# GNU Radio | Async FEC encoder/decoder loopback | Issue during decoding?

Tags: channelcoding, gnuradio

I have implemented a loopback flowgraph intending to perform the following:

1. FEC encode (repetition code) an input stream `in16_2.dat`
2. Store the encoded stream as `out16_2_fec_async_enc.dat`
3. FEC decode the encoded stream and store it as `out16_2_fec_async_dec.dat`

Follows the implemented flowgraph:

[image]

**My expectation:** I was hoping that `out16_2_fec_async_dec.dat` would be equal to `in16_2.dat`.

**What really happened:** `out16_2_fec_async_dec.dat` was empty.
I can confirm that the encoded data, `out16_2_fec_async_enc.dat`, is apparently correct, by running:

```
$ xxd -b in16_2.dat
00000000: 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111 01010101 01010101  ....UU
00000006: 10101010 10101010

$ xxd -b out16_2_fec_async_enc.dat
00000000: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00000006: 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......
0000000c: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 00001111 00001111  ......
00000012: 00001111 00001111 00001111 00001111 00001111 00001111  ......
00000018: 11110000 11110000 11110000 11110000 11110000 11110000  ......
0000001e: 11110000 11110000                                      ..
```

Also, the confirmation that `out16_2_fec_async_dec.dat` is empty:

```
$ xxd -b out16_2_fec_async_dec.dat
```

I wonder what may be missing in this setup?
Please let me know if additional information is needed.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the FEC Async Decoder expects the input to be soft decisions with one decision per item instead of packed PDUs.

Here's a working example:

[image]

Encoder deployment:

- Packed: yes
- Rev. unpacking: yes
- Rev. packing: yes

Repack Bits:

- Packet alignment: Output
- Endieness: LSB

Decoder deployment:

- Packed: yes
- Rev. packing: yes